# Calculus find shaded region

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I have this math problem:

[image]

First: I found the integral from $-1$ to $3$ of $|x^2+3|$ and got $64/3$

Second: I found the integral from $-1$ to $3$ of $|x|$ and got $5$

Finally: I subtracted $5$ from $64/3$ and got $49/3$

However $49/3$ is wrong, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you really mean the absolute values $|\cdots|$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the form $$\int_a^b f(x)-g(x)dx$$ since the first integral contains a negative part of the function $y=x$ and this part gives negative area i.e. the value 5 is not true
The right one is
$$\int_{-1}^3 x^2+3-xdx=52/3$$

Comment: So, the answer is 52/3?